# Displaying a diamond shape in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Hi I am trying to display a diamond pattern that should only work for odd integers, e.g. given n = 5,
the pattern should look like this:

```
  *
 ***
*****
 ***
  *
```

My code so far can only display:

```
*
***
*****
***
*
```

My code:

```
def diamond(n):
  if n % 2 == 0 or n < 0:
    return None
  for i in range(1,n+1, 2):
    print(i * "*")
  for j in range(n-2,0,-2):
    print(j * "*")
```

I can't quite figure out how to add the white spaces

Comment: Just like you can print a `*` by using `"*"`, you can print a space by using `" "`.

Answer (score 2):

You use `center`. Literally that's all you do. If you are trying to center stuff you use `center`. Just tell it the width (here it is `n`).

```
def diamond(n):
  if n % 2 == 0 or n < 0:
    return None
  for i in range(1,n+1, 2):
    print((i * "*").center(n))
  for j in range(n-2,0,-2):
    print((j * "*").center(n))

diamond(7)
```

```
$ python3 lucy.py 
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
 ***** 
  ***  
   *
```

Comment: I have been coding in python for 2-3 years, built amazing GUIs, ML projects, websites in python. But never came across `string.center` or f-string's center method, well there is first time for everything

Comment: We had it in class.

Answer (score 1):

Use ' ' and multiply with the amount of spaces required (which is half of the difference between `n` and current amount of asterixes):

i.e.

```
' ' * 3 => '   ' # Three spaces
```

Code:

```
def diamond(n):
  if n % 2 == 0 or n < 0:
    return None
  for i in range(1,n+1, 2):
    print(' '*((n-i)//2) + i * "*")
  for j in range(n-2,0,-2):
    print(' '*((n-j)//2) + j * "*")

diamond(11)
```

Output:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
***********
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```